# Program of prime generators in many online judges not getting accepted even after trying a lot

Tags: c++

There is a problem "Prime generators" in spoj.pl n codechef.com. I have successfully solved it but it is not getting submitted even after trying a lot. Please help.
I am getting a wrong answer even though I think it is correct. It is satisfying all the cases known to me. The problem statement is (taken from http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/):

```
Input

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10).
In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n
<= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output

For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per
line, test cases separated by an empty line.
```

Here's my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define LLI long long int
#define sll(n) scanf("%lld",&n)
#define s(n) scanf("%d",&n)

int main()
{
    LLI m,n;
    int t,count=0;
    s(t);
    while(t--)
    {
        sll(m);
        sll(n);
        int a[32000]={0};
        int b[100005]={0};
        for(LLI i=2;i*i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(!a[i])
            {
                for(LLI j=i*i;j*j<=n;j=j+i)
                {
                    a[j]=1;
                }
                if(!(m%i))
                    b[0]=1;
                for(LLI j=i-(m%i);j<=n-m;j=j+i)
                {
                    if(m+j!=i)
                        b[j]=1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(m==1)
                b[0]=1;
            for(LLI i=0;i<=n-m;i++)
            {
                if(!b[i]){
                    printf("%lld\n",m+i);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            printf("%d",count);
        }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not accepted might mean a lot of things -- performance being one such issue. Do you know why it isn't getting accepted? Did you at least try to prove that the program works? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Well, first of all, your program does not compile *as is*. Second thing is, you are hardcoding a maximum number of primes. Maybe the online test require more and therefore your program fails.

Comment: I am getting a wrong answer. I tried debugging it but was unsuccessful. The problem link is: http://www.spoj.pl/problems/PRIME1/

Comment: @veyRoN It would help us to answer your question if you showed us (by copying and pasting what you are talking about) what you mean by "wrong answer". Do you mean that you are getting a compiler error, or maybe that the output of the program is not correct? I agree with @Cicada; this program does not compile as it is. Could that be your problem?

Comment: A stack overflow is also a likely failure reason. Your program uses about 500K of stack space, which is quite a lot. Perhaps the test environment uses a smaller stack than this.

Comment: You should decide if it's a C or C++ program. The question is tagged "c", but you do `using namespace std`, which is C++. However, you don't use any C++ features. So decide which you want.

Comment: @Daniel.J.Shapiro: It just shows wrong answer. It means that the output files dont match. The program is getting complied successfully but the output is not correct.

Comment: @ugoren: I was using c but was trying to advance to c++. The main reason of using c++ was so that I can dynamically declare the variables.

Comment: Perhaps don't print `count` in the end, it is not asked for, and it's not printed correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is really weird.
You use the well-known sieve method, setting `a[j]=1` for every composite `j`. Now all you should do is print any `j` in the desired range, for which `a[j]==0`.
But instead, you have the `b` array, and I just can't understand what you're trying to do with it.

Another point is that you end by printing the number of primes you've found.
The problem didn't ask for it, so an automated judge is very likely to fail you because of it (it will consider this number as one of the primes, and it isn't).

Comment: Sorry the no. of primes was added by me for checking how many nos. are printed as I was debugging it. The array a[] is for the primes which are < sqrt(n) and are just for checking. I hav to print the prime nos. which are between m and n which are in b[].